# Android bumping gradle support libraries from anything above 23.1.1 cause weird ui behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I'm currently developing an app, which uses an old version of the android support libraries (current version is 27.0.1, my project has a combination of 23.1.1 and 23.0.1.

I tried along the years to update the version to the latest (really any version above the current), as well as aligning all the support libraries version, but when I do, my Recycler Views are starting to misbehave (weird spacing, crashes, etc...), screenshot comparisons:

Before:

[image]
[image]

After:

[image]
[image]

I have absolutely no idea how to fix it, any help will be greatly appreciated!

New gradle dependencies that cause the bugs (after):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'

    compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:core:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    compile 'org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.5.2'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.0'
    compile(name: 'tealium-5.0.4', ext: 'aar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'

    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

Production (before) gradle dependencies, that works:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'

    compile 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:core:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    compile 'org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:0.5.2'
    compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.0'
    compile(name: 'tealium-5.0.4', ext: 'aar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.9'
    annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.9'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'

    // Required -- JUnit 4 framework
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // Optional -- Mockito framework
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```